# HDMI problem with monitor, Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, hdmi, display-resolution

I have a problem using Ubuntu with an external monitor. Every time I connect it to my HDMI port the image in the monitor starts blinking, as if it can't find a correct resolution. This never happened with Ubuntu 16.04. and it started when I updated it to 18.04.

I hope YouTube can help me. Sorry for my bad English.

Here is a link to a video where I show what happens:
https://youtu.be/mhpTU-WECPk. Sorry for the noise; I was using a fan.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps installing the newest HWE-Stack by

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack